# How can you configure Jenkins Pipeline so you can automatically send an email with a custom body?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, email-ext

I'm trying to have Jenkins pipeline automatically send an email, but with a custom body. The pipeline is called from a web application by a button, so I was thinking about having a text box there to write the desired message before the button is pressed. However, I don't know how this chunk of text can get sent to Jenkins.

Right now the pipeline is sending emails through emailext, with the body message hardcoded. I know I can pass data from a web app to Jenkins with the Build With Parameters API, which I'm currently using for a Username and Password field, but sending a whole email message as a parameter sounds incorrect.

```
  emailext (
        subject: "---subject---",
        body: """Hi, 

This is the hardcoded message that I would the user to have flexibility to create themselves
        """,
        to: "---list of recipients---"
       )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use something like this, where you could add REGEX and EXCERPT to customize your mail content

```
emailext(
    to: "email_list",
    subject: "Subject",
    body: '''$BUILD_URL
          ${BUILD_LOG_REGEX, regex="DRYRUN.*DRYRUN.*DRYRUN",maxMatches=1, showTruncatedLines=false}
          ${BUILD_LOG_EXCERPT, start="EMAIL CONTENT:",end="END OF EMAIL CONTENT"}''',
    recipientProviders: [[$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider']]
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function ready to be executed, you can also add an attachment.
Adapt to your needs.

```
def sendMail() {
    def body = """
            <html>
               <body>
                  <p>Hello</p>
                  <p><img src="cid:screenshot.jpg" alt="screenshot"/></p>
                  <ul>
                     <li><strong>Jenkins Build URL:</strong> ${env.BUILD_URL}</li>
                  </ul>
               </body>
            </html>
            """
    emailext(to: recipient, subject: 'SUCCESS : ' + subject, body: body, mimeType: 'text/html', attachmentsPattern: 'screenshot.jpg')
}
```

Comment: Hi Coldplayer, thanks for your answer! However I don't think it is what I am looking for. I don't see how the body can be customized in this by a normal user through some sort of text input. There's no communication between where the input data probably is (a web app) and Jenkins, which is something that I've been stumped on.

Answer (score 0):

Ist thing you job needs a parameter MAILTEST and then you can just this parameter in the body of the email just like coldplayer proposed.

Honestley for I used https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Generic+Webhook+Trigger+Plugin
because the default trigger support only a kind of token as parameter on the rest interface.